# cut string length of object parameter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of objects that have all of the parameters displayed in a table using ng-repeat.

Occasionally, the Title parameter of an object will be very long and therefore makes the table stretch at certain spots. I have tried using filter but I think that would cut off the rows shown in the table, not the characters of a random object parameter.

Is there a way I can truncate this title to a certain length and add "..." at the end? Apologies if this has been asked before but my research found no answers I needed.

Comment: This should be solved on the `css` level using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a javascript function to force a maximum length of your text:

```
$scope.forceMaxLength = function(s, maxLength) {
     if(s.length > maxLength) {
         return Array.prototype.slice.apply(s, [0, maxLength-3]).join('') + '...';
     } else {
         return s;
     }
}
```

Now you can just use this in your angular template:

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <h3>{{ forceMaxLength(item.title, 25) }}</h3>
   </div>
```

Having said that, using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in your css would probably be a better solution.

The reason for this is that text will have a width that's made up of the sum of the width of each character, and the character widths can vary.

These two strings both have thirty-four characters:

> iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
>
> MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM

If you wanted to truncate these strings so they would fit into a given width, you would want the truncate point to be at different positions in the respective strings.

Comment: I really appreciate it, I ended up going with your first suggestion. While I would have preferred to use ellipsis, the styling was affecting the size of the area the text was in and not the text itself. I am really happy with this solution though since any parameter that has that kind of length will now be shortened, making the lines much more visible.